# Algorithmic Complexity - Difficulty Understanding Example

Tags: algorithm, loops, time-complexity, big-o

Here are the two loops for reference, could someone please explain how the second nested loop is **theta(n)**? I understand the outside loop is iterating log n times as the incrementer is compound assigning to itself and multiplying by 2 effectively becomin some value 2 to the power of x but is less than n. So then on the inside loop we are effectively iterating k times for each power of 2 increase, would that not mean the the number of operations would be **log(n**)? I found other explanations but they still don't effectively help break it down. Thanks for any help in advance.

```
sum1 = 0;
for (k=1; k<=n; k*=2)    // Do log n times
   for (j=1; j<=n; j++)  // Do n times
      sum1++;

sum2 = 0;
for (k=1; k<=n; k*=2)    // Do log n times
   for (j=1; j<=k; j++)  // Do k times
      sum2++;
```

Comment: What is 1+2+4+8+...+2^p?

Comment: Not sure I am following, summing up those values are dependent on n, yes? So would that mean that mean we are conducting worst-case n such ops? I just can't make the jump for some reason, is it because k is some constant value?

Comment: Look at what I wrote. There is no n in that comment. Don't try to solve too many problems at once; find that sum first, then look at your nested loops.